# Seaborn FacetGrid: More than one variable for columns

Tags: python, seaborn

I have data like

```
cat_1 cat_2 values
A     1     ...
A     2     ...
B     1     ...
B     2     ...
```

I want to make a `FacetGrid` plot where each unique `cat_1, cat_2` pair gets a facet. Normally I would use `row="cat_1", col="cat_2"` in the `FacetGrid` constructor, but for formatting reasons I need all the facets on one row.

I could obviously make a column combining these two categorical variables, but then each facet will have a title like `cats = A, 1`. This will make it harder to perceive that the facets belong to two groups. Instead, I want the titles displayed hierarchically, like:

[image: hand-drawn approximation of the layout I want]

Is there any way to do this with Seaborn?